# Method must be overridden in [proguard.optimize.peephole.ClassMerger] if ever called

Tags: android, proguard

```
Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2013-04-04 16:25:20 - ] Note: there were 157 duplicate class definitions.
[2013-04-04 16:25:20 - ] Error: Method must be overridden in [proguard.optimize.peephole.ClassMerger] if ever called
```

I have tried every possible solution found on SO. There were around 2000 duplicates which now came down to 157. I have some external jars in my project too. This is my proguard.cfg file:

```
-dontwarn android.support.**

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider

-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
    public void set*(...);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.content.Context {
   public void *(android.view.View);
   public void *(android.view.MenuItem);
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    static android.os.Parcelable$Creator CREATOR;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

-keep class com.flurry.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.flurry.**

-keep class org.apache.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.apache.**


-dump proguard/class_files.txt 
-printseeds proguard/seeds.txt 
-printusage proguard/unused.txt 
-printmapping proguard/mapping.txt
```

This application is for Android 4.0
Can you kindly let me know whats causing this and how do I go about in fixing it.

Comment: did you figure out the problem? Facing similar issue.

Comment: struggling with the same thing...

Answer (score 0):

Merging my project's proguard config with one from ${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt did the trick.

This error mostly happens with 3rd party build systems (e.g. Maven), which don't know about default proguard config.

UPD: ...because of the following content of default config:

```
# Optimization is turned off by default. Dex does not like code run
# through the ProGuard optimize and preverify steps (and performs some
# of these optimizations on its own).
-dontoptimize
```